# Email sent through localhost but not sent when I try to send from my Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Email sent through localhost but not sent when I try to send from my Server.

What to Do.

**note :** I was use `port` 25 and `host` : mail.mydomain.com.

> Failure sending mail.

Could you help me please?

I have used this code:

```
public static string SendMail(string host , string from , string pass , int port , string pTo, string subject, string body, string attach)
    {
        string Host = host;
        string ReceiverEmailAddres = pTo;
        string SenderEmailAddresss = from;
        string SenderEmailPassword = pass;

        SmtpClient MyMail = new SmtpClient();

        MailMessage MyMsg = new MailMessage();

        MyMail.Host = Host;

        MyMail.Port = port;
        MyMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ReceiverEmailAddres));
        MyMsg.Subject = subject;

        if (attach != string.Empty)
        {
            Attachment data = new Attachment(attach);
            MyMsg.Attachments.Add(data);
        }

        MyMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        MyMsg.From = new MailAddress(SenderEmailAddresss);

        MyMsg.Body = body;


        MyMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential MyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(SenderEmailAddresss, SenderEmailPassword);
        MyMail.Credentials = MyCredentials;

        try
        {
            MyMail.Send(MyMsg);
            return "ok";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your firewall configurations if it is blocking your outgoing connection with **port 25 (used to send e-mails)**. Due to the lack of 50 rep points i was not able to first comment and ask if you already tried this or what your firewall configuration looks like. If you want to receive emails also you should check if your firewall is blocking the incoming connection to **port 110 (POP3) or 143 (IMAP4, no TLS) / 993 (IMAP4, TLS)**.